# TYPO3 Extbase Repository Query: How to find records in M:N relation where several values for N are given?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-flow

We have a simple model *Company*. Each company can have one ore more departments *Dept*. Each department is of a certain type *Type*.

Now we need a query where all companies are returned, which have a department of type X **and** one of type Y at least (i.e. each returned company has two or more departments, at least one X and one Y).

How can that be done with a query?

This query gives no results if getTypes returns more than one type.

```
if (count($types = $demand->getTypes()) > 0) {
    foreach ($types as $type)
        $constraints[] = $query->contains('dept.type', $type);
}

$result = $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($query->logicalAnd($constraints)))->execute();
```

This query returns results for type X **or** Y

```
if (count($types = $demand->getTypes()) > 0) {
    $constraints[] = $query->in('dept.type', $types);
}
```

The tables look like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dept` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `company` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);
```

Comment: I of course could do one query for each type and then take the intersecting set... but that's not very elegant!

Comment: The field "type" in table "dept" is an unsigned int(10). How can there be more than one relation? I know the comma sepearted assignment but this requires a string. I also know the 1:n, but this needs an extra field in table type and does not make sense and a M:N relation requires and extra table. Check your TCA and backend setting if everything is working fine there.

Comment: Every department has only one type, so a single int field is fine. But a company has one or more departments. In this sense, the department table is the mn-table--- All the relations in this model are fine. It's just about finding a query solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that $query->contains() only works properly with plain _mm tables.

So this is what I did: I just added a view to the DB which has the required fields for a _mm table:

```
CREATE VIEW `company_type_mm` AS
SELECT 
    `company` AS `uid_local`, 
    `type` AS `uid_foreign`,
    0 AS `sorting`,
    0 AS `sorting_foreign` 
FROM `dept`;
```

Then I added a new field *dept* to the TCA of the *company* table:

```
'type' => array(
    ...
    'config' => array(
        'foreign_table' => 'type',
        'MM' => 'company_type_mm',
        ...
    )
)
```

And now I get the right results for companies which have departments of type A **and** type B like this:

```
if (count($types = $demand->getTypes()) > 0) {
    foreach ($types as $type)
        $constraints[] = $query->contains('type', $type);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (count($types = $demand->getTypes()) > 0) {
    foreach ($types as $type)
        $constraints[] = $query->contains('dept.type', $type);
}
```

You do not show the further processing.

If you need AND operation use this:

```
$result = $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($query->logicalAnd($constraints)))->execute();
```

If you need OR operation use this:

```
$result = $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($query->logicalOr($constraints)))->execute();
```

HTH

Comment: The first code block is just the quote of yours. But you don't show the further processing. If you want as result X AND Y, try the $query->contains constraint and the matching method call with AND operation as I wrote.

Comment: Ok, sry, my fault, I didn't read correct.
What about a two step query ?  Did you try this already ?
First : Get all Dept by type.
Next : Get all Companies by Dept.